# Any ideas on how to install WildTangent with Wine?

Tags: wine, games

I have an Acer computer running Ubuntu 17.10. When I was using 17.04 I couldn't even install Big Fish games, but since the upgrade, I have been able to install the later just fine but WildTangent doesn't want to install at all. Does anyone know if this may be in the works to allow the install of these kinds of games or if there might be a workaround on getting them installed? I have a lot of games I have bought through this site and I don't want them to be a waste of money.

Comment: Be sure to also try it through PlayOnLinux. Sometimes things work better with whatever tweaks the PlayOnLinux software makes to WINE.

Comment: winehq results do not look promising: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13322